# Match aggregation - Away goal rule (soccer/football)

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all I have searched for an answer to my problem, but couldn't find it.
I am learning PHP (procedural) and MySQL and I am currently working on a soccer/football
cup.

The cup is setup like any normal European cup where each team play two legs (home and away) and best team on aggregate goes through to the next round. My problem is that I can't figure out is how to implement the away goal rule. The rule means that if the teams are tied like in the match between Team Blue and Team Red then the winner of that pairing is the team with the most scored goals away. In my example it should be Team Red. They scored 2 goals.

My attempt is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96a50/1).

In my opinon the solution is to get the hgoal value from the second table in the union.

```
 SELECT n.tname as hometeam,t.tname as awayteam,SUM(agoal),SUM(hgoal)
 FROM (
 SELECT id,date,hteam,ateam,hgoal,agoal FROM games
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id,date,ateam,hteam,agoal,**hgoal** FROM games **this table**/ )total
```

From the first table I get values if I use total.agoal, but I can´t get values from the second. If that isn´t possible then I have no clue to solve this.

Thank you in advance for any help I will recieve.

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is very useful, but can you copy the code within to the question? If the fiddle is deleted the question won't be useful for future readers.

Comment: if the output is correct other than that one column should come before the first why can't you just change the order of the columns and alias them to what they truly represent? ie. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96a50/8/0

Comment: Thank you Brian DeMilia, that solved the first problem. The second one remains. Should I use a case statement for the away goal rule?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I renamed hgoal/agoal to hscore/ascore...

```
SELECT tname Team
     , SUM(p) P
     , SUM(w) W
     , SUM(d) D
     , SUM(l) L
     , SUM(f) F
     , SUM(a) A
     , SUM(gd) GD
     , SUM(pts) PTS
  FROM 
     ( SELECT hteam Team
            , 1 P
            , IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) w
            , IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) d
            , IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) l
            , hscore f
            , ascore a
            , hscore-ascore gd
            , CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END pts   
         FROM games 
        UNION 
          ALL
       SELECT ateam
            , 1
            , IF(hscore < ascore,1,0)
            , IF(hscore = ascore,1,0)
            , IF(hscore > ascore,1,0)
            , ascore
            , hscore
            , ascore-hscore 
            , CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM games
     ) tot
  JOIN teams t 
    ON tot.Team=t.id
 GROUP 
    BY Team
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(PTS) DESC ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/273806/1

Comment: Thank you for you solution, but I don´t need a league table. I am creating a cup.